# How to implement push notification using oracle maf

Tags: oracle, oracle-maf

I just tried the the sample code provided by oracle maf for push notifications.I can register through it but when I pass message I didn't receive any message.
this is server code. Can us plz explain how to register in gcm.I registered there but I doubt in that also and is there any way to seeing the message received details in gcm

```
  <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Execute.execute}"
                           text="Refresh"
                           disabled="#{!bindings.Execute.enabled}"
                           id="ctb1" immediate="true"/>
  <af:table value="#{bindings.RegistrationsView1.collectionModel}"
            var="row"
            rows="#{bindings.RegistrationsView1.rangeSize}"
            emptyText="#{bindings.RegistrationsView1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
            fetchSize="#{bindings.RegistrationsView1.rangeSize}"
            rowBandingInterval="0"
            selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.RegistrationsView1.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
            selectionListener="#{bindings.RegistrationsView1.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
            rowSelection="single" id="t1"
            partialTriggers="::ctb1" width="633" inlineStyle="height:189px;">
    <af:column sortProperty="DeviceToken" sortable="false"
               headerText="Device Token" id="c1" width="100">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.DeviceToken}" id="ot5"/>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="DeviceModel" sortable="false"
               headerText="Device Model" id="c3" width="100">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.DeviceModel}" id="ot4"/>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="ApplicationId" sortable="false"
               headerText="Application" id="c5" width="205">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.ApplicationId}" id="ot1"/>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="UserId" sortable="false"
               headerText="User Id" id="c2" width="-5">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.UserId}" id="ot3"/>
    </af:column>
    <af:column sortProperty="SenderId" sortable="false"
               headerText="Sender Id" id="c4" width="100">
      <af:outputText value="#{row.SenderId}" id="ot2"/>
    </af:column>
  </af:table>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
<af:panelGroupLayout layout="scroll"
                     xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
                     id="pgl1">
  <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" partialTriggers="t1">
    <af:panelLabelAndMessage label="#{bindings.DeviceToken.hints.label}"
                             id="plam4">
      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.DeviceToken.inputValue}"
                     id="ot7"/>
    </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
    <af:panelLabelAndMessage label="#{bindings.DeviceModel.hints.label}"
                             id="plam2">
      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.DeviceModel.inputValue}"
                     id="ot6"/>
    </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
    <af:panelLabelAndMessage label="#{bindings.UserId.hints.label}"
                             id="plam1">
      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.UserId.inputValue}"
                     id="ot9"/>
    </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
    <af:panelLabelAndMessage label="#{bindings.ApplicationId.hints.label}"
                             id="plam3">
      <af:outputText value="#{bindings.ApplicationId.inputValue}"
                     id="ot8"/>
    </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
    <af:inputText label="Message" id="it1"
                  value="#{MessageBean.message}"/>
  </af:panelFormLayout>
  <af:commandButton text="Push Message" id="cb1" 
             actionListener="#{MessageBean.pushMessage}"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Comment: Add relevant code to your question.

Comment: You added some ADF code, what does have to do with push and MAF?

Comment: The MAF 2.1.1 extension provides two sample applications – PushDemo, which demonstrates how to receive push notifications in a MAF app, and PushServer, which demonstrates how to send push notifications to a MAF app. The above code is push server code

Comment: I referred this website for push notification in maf  :
https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/how_to_implement_push_notifications

Comment: Are trying to get PushNotification through Oracle-MCS ? If yes I can help you.

Comment: Thank you!!Still now didn't try push notification with mcs

Comment: Did you add any code in LifeCycleImplementation class?

Comment: onMesssage method is not getting invoked when I sent message through server .. can u please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue solved after enabling JSSE on all managed servers including Admin Server (in weblogic server).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have two applications. A server application  (PushServer ) and a mobile application implemented with MAF framework (PushDemo) .I believe you found those after you installed MAF module into JDeveloper.

Secondly, to register with Google Cloud Messaging server, go to [this link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue) , write your app name ( default is PushService ) and your Android package name ( default for sample app is com.oraclecorp.internal.maf.PushSample ). You will get a **GOOGLE API KEY** which you will have to set into the PushServer application, into the MessageBean class (it is a constant there called GOOGLE_APIKEY), and a senderId that you will write into the mobile application ( into **adf-config.xml**  - it is a property called gcmSenderId ).

You will have to run the server project on a public server ( Weblogic probably ) and have your mobile app call the URL where your servlet is - for example : ***http://www.something.com/PushService-ViewController-context-root/registrations*** ), then in your mobile application project, under connections.xml you have two fields that you have to edit :

```
<urlconnection name="SyncService_base_connection" url="http://www.something.com"/>
```

and

```
 <urlconnection name="PushServiceConn" url="http://www.something.com/PushService-ViewController-context-root/registrations"/>
```

You start the app on the device, then check on the application if you registered into the database. Then if you press push for your device, you should receive those notifications straight on the Android device.

For the APNS process things are a little bit complicated, but the tutorial gets you going.

Thanks,

Razvan

Comment: I have tried the above steps and still now I didn't get notifications. But while I send message from server it shows some warning message.

Comment: onMesssage method is not getting invoked when I sent message through server .. can u please help

Comment: @Janak Can you please post/update the warning message? and also can you update if you have resolved the issue?